# Combining Data from Multiple Rows in Simple Database

Tags: sql

I am new to using SQL. I have constructed the following simple database, which has the ID of music albums and the number of copies bought.

[image]

In the `album_ID` column, there are two pieces of data with ID 1. They have `quantity_bought` values of 10 and 4. Is it possible to combine these two rows into one row
which has ID 1 and a total `quantity_bought` value of 14?

Comment: Use aggregate function `SUM()` and `Group By`. So, code should be like `Select album_ID ,SUM(quantity_bought ) as SumAmount FROM yourTable Group By  album_ID `.

Comment: If the comment above is not the solution, please elaborate what you mean by "combine". Do you want to change the data in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
-- your input
sold(album_id,qty_bought) AS (
          SELECT 1,10
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 5
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 4
)
SELECT
  album_id
, SUM(qty_bought) AS quantity_bought
FROM sold
GROUP BY album_id;
album_id|quantity_bought
       1|             14
       2|              5
```